# OpenGL share model data beteen shaders

Tags: opengl, shader

Is there a way to share data between shaders?
Do i just create a VAO and then swich shader programs as needed?
I guess shaders probably need to have the same layout then.

Or do i create VBO-s and per object-shader pair i create the VAO that binds data to shader variables?
This should load most data only once to the OpenGl + i could reuse quite alot.

I tried the second approach, but im not sure if it has reduced memory usage or not. The code pieces in question are below, i hope its enough.

Or is there some other, even better way?

Idea is to reduce the memory usage, and general speedup of the process.

```
void Mesh::bind()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, verticesCount * sizeof(GLfloat), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, nbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, normalCount * sizeof(GLfloat), normals, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, uvCount * sizeof(GLfloat), UVs, GL_STATIC_DRAW);


    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesCount * sizeof(GLuint), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}



void MeshRenderer::init()
{
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getVertexBufferId());
    GLuint posId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("LVertexPos2D");
    glVertexAttribPointer(posId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(posId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getNormalBufferId());
    GLuint normId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("LVertexNorm");
    glVertexAttribPointer(normId, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(normId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getUVBufferId());
    GLuint uvId = shaderProgram->getAttribute("uv");
    glVertexAttribPointer(uvId, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), NULL);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(uvId);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, mesh->getIndexBufferId());

    glBindVertexArray(0);
}

GameObject* GameObject::createCustom(Mesh* mesh)
{
    Texture* texture = new Texture();
    texture->loadFromFile("UV.png", NULL);
    GenericShaderProgram* shader = new GenericShaderProgram("basic.vs", "basic.fs");
    shader->loadProgram();
    return new GameObject(texture, shader, mesh);
}

GameObject::GameObject(Texture* texture, ShaderProgram* program, Mesh* mesh)
{
    this->texture = texture;
    dir = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);
    meshRenderer = new MeshRenderer(mesh, program);
    transform.setRotation(1.57, 1, 0, 0);
    transform.translate(Vector3(0, -2, 0));
    transform.setScale(Vector3(1, 1, 1));
}

//In main.cpp
Mesh* mesh = new Mesh();
    mesh->cubePrimitive();
    mesh->init();

    object = GameObject::createCustom(mesh);
    object2 = GameObject::createCustom(mesh);
    object3 = GameObject::createCustom(mesh);
```

Comment: Looks good. The important thing is that you create VBOs only once. And that's what you do. VAOs just store links and don't contribute much to memory consumption. You might also want to reuse shaders instead of loading the same shader three times. In this case here, you wouldn't even need multiple VAOs, but I guess that's something planned for the future.

Comment: if the other shaders are simple, you can have them in one shader as functions and switch between them using a uniform flag... but if they are large and complex this might get ugly.

Comment: Well this was just simple example. But yea the idea was. like i have multiple same objects. But each has a different shader. may them be simple or complex. doesentmatter, just aslong i dont have to recreate the VBO-s every time.And if you really think about it, createCustom is basically a constructor. everything could be taken out.